# Can you use underscores in table names under the Kohana PHP framework (and how)?

Tags: php, kohana

The underscore is a special character in Kohana and gets translated into a directory separator but since I have a bunch of existing code that uses underscores in table names, I want to know if it's possible to configure Kohana to understand that in some way.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be by putting your model classes in subdirectories of the Model folder.

For example, if you had a table called `user_profiles`, your directories would look like this:

```
application/
...classes/
......model/
.........user/
............profile.php
```

and `profile.php` would be like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access.');

class Model_User_Profile extends ORM 
{
}
```

I would recommend going with the above approach (we use it at the company where I work), as it's the "standard" Kohana way of doing things, so you will have fewer hassles down the road. However, if you need to for some reason, you could also use the `_table_name` property of the `ORM` class (see docs [here](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.orm)):

```
application/
...classes/
......model/
.........userprofile.php
```

and `profile.php` would be like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access.');

class Model_UserProfile extends ORM 
{
    protected $_table_name = 'user_profiles'; // <== manually setting table name
}
```

This can also be helpful if your tables don't quite follow the singular vs. plural convention Kohana uses.

Answer (score 1):

**Kohana** doesnt replace underscores in table names. You can use everything you want in plain queries (`$this->db->query($sql)`), **Database Query Builder** (`$this->from($table_name)->...->execute()`) or any kind of **AR** (**ORM**, **Sprig**, **Jelly** - all of them allow you to set `table_name` property). Also you can use default (calculated from class name) table names as *notJim* described.

Answer (score 0):

Underscores will be translated into directory separator, that's how kohana autoloading works.
But, that's not really matters as you can define `$_table_name` properties in your `model`.

```
class Model_Profile extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'user_profiles';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Because your model name is the table name with last word pluralized by default. I mean that

```
Model_Foo_Bar {
}
```

will be `foo_bars` table which Kohana will try to find by default.